# Internal laptop screen is not avaiable after lid close event, instead multiple times attached

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, gnome, display

I am running Ubuntu 17 on a Surface Pro 4. I had the same issue with Fedora 27. Both running gnome as desktop.

I have a external (DELL) monitor connected to my surface 4. When I close the lid, internal and external display turn off. After opening the lid, only the external screen works, the internal screen stays black and is even not found under devices:

[image]

Any idea how to solve this issue? How can I get my internal display to be used again after lid close event? Also I want to report it on Bugzilla, but what is the right category? New -> Core and then? gnome‑desktop?

Answer (score 1):

The `screen` command is **not** related to physical displays at all, but to multiplexed text-mode terminal sessions. Blame history. `pts-0` is probably the first terminal window you opened.

The command for manipulating the configuration of physical display screens on the command line is `xrandr`.

When you close the laptop lid and the displays turn off, the laptop is probably going to suspend or hibernation mode. I'm not very familiar with the Gnome desktop, but there is probably some way to configure power management to not do that.

Comment: There is no option to configure what shall be done when lid close event happens. I don't think it goes into hibernation or go to standby mode because if it does turn into one of those modes both screens stay black.

Comment: I will addapt my question.